# Possible to have a synchronous http request in bootstrap for angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I need to generate a user access sessionid for accessing the api to use everywhere. Rather than some sort of di with sessionservice and do some sort of

```
sessionService.subscribe(x => http.get(`api/${x.sessionId}/method`).subscribe(y => this.datastore = y)
```

I'd rather just access a guaranteed sessionid.

```
http.get(`api/${sessionService.sessId}/method`).subscribe(x => this.datastore = x);
```

the session service will mostly be pulling from localstore but the first hit will be ajax and I'd like to hold up the bootstrap process until it is finished.

Does anyone know of a mechanism for providing the session storage and waiting for the ajax?

Comment: Are you aware about the async/await support in Typescript? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/03/what-about-asyncawait/

Comment: Yes, i'm dying for it to be implemented. they pulled it out of the 2.0 release if you haven't heard. At the moment it isn't implemented in the browser

Answer (score 0):

> hold up the bootstrap process until it is finished.

You will have to use something *that isn't bound to angular*. Hence not angular's `http` and something like `fetch` : https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: I was hoping to use angular services and that there was some sort of mechanism in the bootstrap process that would allow this but I may end up going with something like this.